# How to get newly created comment having _id only instead of all posts with all comments. See description for detailed info please

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating something like fb, I want to implement comment create functionality which I did successfully, Now I want to return newly added comment only with _id field so that I can update frontend accordingly... Can you help me Please

My schema is:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', required: true },
    content: { type: String, required: true, set: function (value) { return value.trim() } },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    likes: {
        totalLikes: { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0 },
        usersLikedPost: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', default: []}]
    },
    comments: [{
        userId: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', required: true },
        comment: { type: String, required: true }
    }]
});

module.exports = model('textPosts', postSchema);
```

Controller for adding new Comment is here:

```
exports.comment = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id, comment } = req.body;

  let post = await TextPost.findById(Types.ObjectId(id));

  if (!post)
    return res.status(404).end();

  post.comments.push({ userId: req.userId, comment });
  await post.save();

  post = await TextPost.populate(post, 
    { path: 'comments.userId', select: 'username _id' }); // returns complete post with all comments and some other data

  return res.status(201).json({ msg: 'return here newly created comment only' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate pipeline arrayElemAt, below query will return the last element of array

```
db.TextPost.aggregate(
 {
   $project: {
     last: {
       $arrayElemAt: [
         "$comments",
         -1
       ]
     }
   }
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $slice

Latest 5

```
 db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: -5 } } )
```

First 5

```
db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: 5 } } )
```

From to

```
 db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: [ 20, 10 ] } } )
```

Please check the below link

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/